# WSO2: How can i keep different session in each browser tab

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to login to my application with the user "sample@tenant.com" in one tab and "sample1@tenant1.com" in another user.

And I want both tabs should be active with different tenant authentication.

How can I achieve this in WSO2IS?
I am using WSO2 Identity server version 5.3.0

In other words, How can I restrict my session within a browser tab?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot, it's a feature of the browsers

however - in many browsers you can open incognito/anonymous windows with separate identity/cookies, there you can have another user logged in

Comment: Banking applications already doing this. You can open two different user sessions in two different browser tabs for bank of america online banking.

Comment: @Sathya sessions in wso2is (and many other products) are based on a single /simple cookie. Then supporting multiple sessions needs to be done on another level (url parameter, tailored cookies, ..) It's not something wso2is is built for (on the contrary, it is built to maintain and remember the sessions for sso). or.. do you mean bank of america is using wso2is?

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you can use a proxy server such as apache http server and configure virtual hosts in the proxy configuration such that the same Identity Server instance will be exposed as two different hosts. With this approach you can maintain different authenticated sessions in the same browser. Please refer [my article](https://medium.com/@technospace/how-to-maintain-two-authenticated-sessions-in-the-same-browser-wso2-identity-server-3009fca9c5a1) for more information including proxy configurations.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion. You need to disclose if it is your blog/article